# I want to use a php file for initial load only of jquery datatables

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatables

I am new to jQuery DataTables (datatables.net) I do not want to configure for serverside loading, but do want to use a php file to initally load the table.

Here is my html file:

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jQuery/datatables.min.css"></link>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

     <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

         $('#faxList').DataTable( {
                ajax: {
                    url: 'php/Data.php',
                    dataSrc: 'transactions'
                },
                columns: [
                    { data: 'PROCESS_DATE' },
                    { data: 'PROCESS_STATUS' },
                    { data: 'PDF_FILE_NAME' },
                    { data: 'REF_ID' },
                    { data: 'ADDITIONAL_INFO' }

                ]
            });

        });
    </script>

    <title>NCompass Failed Fax Monitor</title>

</head>

<body>


    <h2>NCompass Failed Fax Monitor</h2>
    <br>
    <table width="100%" class="display" cellspacing="0" id="faxList">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Process Date</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>PDF File</th>
                <th>Reference ID</th>
                <th>Error Description</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

    </table>
</body>
```

The above code Returns zero rows.  However if i run the php directly and paste the output in a text file, like the below code (notice different url) I get the desired result.  I am pretty sure that datatables is attempting to read my php file as data rather than running it, but I don't know how to fix it.

```
 $('#faxList').DataTable( {
                ajax: {
                    url: 'php/Data.php',
                    dataSrc: 'transactions'
                },
                columns: [
                    { data: 'PROCESS_DATE' },
                    { data: 'PROCESS_STATUS' },
                    { data: 'PDF_FILE_NAME' },
                    { data: 'REF_ID' },
                    { data: 'ADDITIONAL_INFO' }

                ]
            });

        });
```